# How to implement actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

### I am trying to use actionbar sherlock

I have implemented a sample project using actionbarsherlock

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // First Menu Button
        menu.add("Help")
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.HelpButtonClickListener)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

        // Second Menu Button
        menu.add("Like")
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.LikeButtonClickListener)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

        // Third Menu Button
        menu.add("Exit")
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.ExitButtonClickListener)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/ActionBarSherlock" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### **My Present output**:: *Sherlockbar is at bottom*

[image]

---

### What i am trying to do :: 2 sherlock bars one at top and one at bottom. both must be different bars

[image]

so that i can use them for different listeners

Is it possible ?

**How to implement this !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement only one action bar. There is no way to implement two action bar. Except when you split action bar. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) link to learn more about splitting action bar.